# How can I read a variable from another component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-context

I receive these two values from two  options elements in a component using React.
Question:  How can I read these two variables from another component?

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {   
    const valueFilterActive = document.getElementById("activeFilter").value;
    const valueFilterName = document.getElementById("bussFilter").value;
    alert(valueFilterName+valueFilterActive);   
 };
```

The second component code line:

```
 return (
    <> 
      <div className="col-md-4 p-2">
        <FirstComponent/>
  
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-8 p-1 ">
          <div className={ valueFilterActive  === 'Activado' ? "text-success" : "text-primary card mb-1"} key={link.id}>
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Is the second component is included in the first component ? Can you provide the full component code ?

Comment: The opposite: The first component its included in the second component. I just add more code in order to understand what I need. Thanks M. Faisal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want read variables from another component you can use many ways. It depends how you chain those components.

If the base value is in parent and you want to pass it to child use props https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

```
const element = <Welcome data1 ={valueFilterActive} data2 ={valueFilterName} />;

function Welcome(props) {  
return <h1>Hello, {props.valueFilterName} {props.valueFilterActive}</h1>;
}
```

If the base value is in child and you want to pass it to parent use callback function
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

But if its more complicated way i recommend using Context Hook
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

(PS: Also in react you don`t use `getElementById` but another hook called useRef
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: for this case "If the base value is in child and you want to pass it to parent use callback function" it would better if you gave an example as you did with the first case

Answer (score 1):

```
// in the component that renders <FirstComponent> create  hooks for values you'd like to track
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({});

return (
  <> 
    <div className="col-md-4 p-2">
      <FirstComponent onChange={setInputValues}/>

    </div>
    <div className="col-md-8 p-1 ">
        <div className={ valueFilterActive  === 'Activado' ? "text-success" : "text-primary card mb-1"} key={link.id}>


// in your <FirstComponent> call setInputValues and set variables 
const handleInputChange = (e) => {   
  const valueFilterActive = document.getElementById("activeFilter").value;
  const valueFilterName = document.getElementById("bussFilter").value;
  // this will set `inputValues` variable to be an object with `valueFilterActive` and `valueFilterName` properties
  setInputValues({valueFilterActive, valueFilterName})
  alert(valueFilterName+valueFilterActive);   
};
```